# Send push message to apple sandbox

Tags: ios, push

I'm currently working on push notification workflow developed by another developer of my company.
I have a question about the sandbox for push notification.
I have generated a .pem for my production environment.
I have tested id with openssl as describe in [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1).

When i make the test to `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com` url, the connection is ok even though i don't use the developement key and cert files (i use the prod file).

If i build and send push message to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com with my prod pem file, the message will be send to the prod devices or dev devices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as a production device or a development device. There are devices with either a production build or a development build of your application.

You can only send a push to a development build of your app using the development environment, and likewise you can only send a push to a production build of your app using the production environment.

Production and dev builds are signed using different profiles, and this results in the push token that your app obtains being different, if you try to send a push using the sandbox environment but using a production push token then it will be rejected, and similarly attempting to use the production environment with a dev push token.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. After the documentation reading, it was a little confusing but now it's ok.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set your gateway proper, use the proper PEM whether Dev PEM or Dist PEM.  Xcode needs Dev profile and certificate to run and test with Dev PEM

Comment: Enhance your answer with screenshots and examples.